# Undo DbContext.Add()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext, undo

I have the problem, that I've added a entity to my DbContext using `_db.Article.Add(artícle)`, but want to UNDO this before I'm executing `_db.SaveChanges`.

I haven't found anything, but I tried to use `_db.ChangeTracker` sadly not figuring it out yet. Further more `_db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Deleted` or `_db.Article.Remove(article)` will not work either, because the entity isnt in the Database yet...

Is there any possibility to delete it out of the list of changes?

Comment: Why is it going into the changeset if you don't want it committed?

Comment: I'm using an external termination library, which isnt corresponding very well with adding and deleting entities. First it adds the entities to the dbcontext, then it merges conflicts between the terminations and finally deletes dupe-terminations (using an action, so I can decide, how to delete them)... After all these step I exectute SaveChanges

Comment: remove should work just fine (if you have the actual object) by removing it you arent saying delete you are just removing it from the tracker so it wont get added yet

Comment: Ah, I think, there's no problem with the actual removal, its not even added to the context somehow oO  But I've got another question now: When it comes to _db.Article.Find() will it also fined changetracker-entities?

Comment: @user2111892 yes they are stored in context.YourSet.Local

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the explicit implementation of [DbContext.IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696590(v=vs.110).aspx) to get to the underlying [ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Detach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach.aspx) your entity, something like;

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)_db).ObjectContext.Detach(article);
```

A syntactically cleaner way would be to extend your DbContext with a method;

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext 
{
    public void Detach(object entity) { ObjectContext.Detach(entity); }
}
```

...which would allow you to simply do;

```
_db.Detach(article);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove works just fine, the following produces no change in SQL (no insert or delete statements)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            var entity = new MyEntity();

            ctx.MyEntities.Add(entity);
            ctx.MyEntities.Remove(entity);

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is because SQL is not generated until the savechanges call in EF. Its not until this point that EF evaluates the entire graph and persists changes which dont match its initial snapshot to the database.